# Can't get sphinx to link under toctree to another document

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, toctree

I'm attempting to learn sphinx and am stuck on just the basic examples. I'm being given the following error on a `make html` in the source directory.

```
Running Sphinx v1.1.3
loading pickled environment... not yet created
building [html]: targets for 2 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] intro                                                 
/home/owner/Desktop/doc/index.rst:11: ERROR: Error in "toctree" directive:
invalid option block.

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   intro.rst
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... /home/owner/Desktop/doc/intro.rst:: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] intro                                                  
writing additional files... genindex search
copying static files... done
dumping search index... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 2 warnings.

Build finished. The HTML pages are in _build/html.
```

I also tried referencing `intro` instead of `intro.rst` neither seems to work. `index.rst` and `intro.rst` are in the same directory. I made the project with `sphinx-quickstart` and all default options.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need a blank line between a directive's options and its content. You also don't need the file extension. Change it to this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   intro
```

Comment: That damn blank line, took my 6 hours!