# Sphinx: modules.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree

Tags: python, python-sphinx, toctree

Trying to generate documentation with Sphinx.

First using: `sphinx-apidoc`
Then using: `sphinx-build html`

And I got this warning about the `modules.rst` file.
The file exists, the html is also generated, it definitely looks like a table of content.

I read every topic I could find about the subject, none solve the issue (correct positioning of the modules declation in the `index.rst` file, using the `.. include::` directive...)

I do not know what to do to make it work

Here is a copy of my `index.rst` file, maybe you'll see something that I do not. The generated rst files are located in the `sources` folder

```
Welcome to documentation!
=====================================
    
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4
   :caption: Contents:

   modules

   
Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

I also get this message:

```
..\doc\sphinx\index.rst:4: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'modules'
```

If I replace modules by another document, I get the following:

```
\doc\sphinx\index.rst:4: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'opsimtest'
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... \doc\sphinx\_apidocs\modules.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree
```

So it looks like even if I name another document in the toctree, it's still looking for modules.rst (and does not see the other document, which was however built into a html file)

In this topic: [Can't get sphinx to link under toctree to another document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426496/cant-get-sphinx-to-link-under-toctree-to-another-document) the error message states `intro.rst` instead of `modules.rst`.
Edit: As I told, I unfortunately already read the others threads and they did not solve my issue. It's still broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In reST white space has meaning. The directive and its options must be separated from its content with a blank line.

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 4
    :caption: Contents:

    _apidocs/modules
```